# How can I make use of Vue .env settings in a .js file?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I have a .js file in which I would like to read the value of a Vue environment variable, as set via a .env.* file.

In my main.js file, where the Vue instance is created, I can read those variables/settings via "process.env. ...".
However, in this other .js file, I cannot find a way to read them there. No "process.env. ..." variables are visible there. And I also cannot find them via the "this.*" object or the "Vue.*" object (whichever is set at that point in the code). E.g. not via something like "Vue.process.env. ...".
I import Vue at the beginning of this file via:

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
```

but that doesn't help in any way, it seems.

How can I read these variables there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

process.env is accessible only in the node environment. If you want to use it in your client side code, you can use webpack.DefinePlugin; in Vue Cli 3, this is automatic for all variables that start with VUE_APP_: [Env Variables Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

Comment: I had not noticed that only variables that start with "VUE_APP_" are visible by default. And indeed, the variable which is visible in the code, starts with that prefix (mostly by coincidence), whereas the one which did not work yet does not.
Thanks for this tip: I completely missed this crucial prefix part!

Comment: What I discovered (or rather: found out after much frustration & googling), is that these variables are set once at built time. What this means, is that if you run your code through a debugger, these specific variables will show up as undefined in (say) a watch list. Which confused me a lot, but makes sense if you know how (and when) these variables are set..!